# Drive PLCC6 LED

Tags: led, constant-current, led-driver

have a question about PLCC6 LEDs. All three of them in one housing are white.
I want to drive them with the Infineon LED driver BCR402U and a 12V powersupply.

Since one package houses three LEDs, is it ok to put these three LEDs in parallel?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2y2dX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or should they all be driven by a seperate constant current source. Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSm9Rv.png)</sup>

What is the likehood that one LED in a single PLCC6 housing fails and kills all other leds?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not drive them in series?

Comment: Since I only got 12V and every LED needs 3V I can only drive 3 LEDs in series. If I wire all LEDs in one housing in series the PCB would be difficult to route.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. The routing would go under the package. It's fairly simple.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Either would work. The concerns about parallel led VF issues is unfounded in these applications. The diodes in the same package are so closely matched from the same source process that the difference in their VF is infinitesimal and will not result in any significant change in current through them. This is how many leds are wired in commercial applications.

The third option you have dismissed. You can easily route the 3 diodes of one of these packages in series. The trace would go under it in a z shape. This is how it's done in many commercial applications as well. No vias are needed, easily done in a single layer.

Comment: This is not true: "The diodes in the same package are so closely matched from the same source process that the difference in their VF is infinitesimal".  OSRAM paper says: "tolerances and material properties, Vf can vary between LEDs even if they are from the same wafer. "

Comment: The difference is miniscule. At no point did I say there was no difference.

Comment: The difference is NOT miniscule,[minuscule] nor infinitesimal even if on the wafer.  LEDs are not manufactured like typical semi-conductors using lithography.  They are grown on a substrate where tolerance is difficult to maintain.  LEDs Vf can range from min to max on a single wafer.

Answer (score 0):

LEDs should not be connected in parallel.  Each LED has a slightly different forward voltage (Vf). When wired in parallel they cannot run at their normal Vf and the current will not be equally divided.

Use 3 constant current sources.  The easiest way is to use a 3 output CCR.

A good choice for this project would be the [Microchip CL320](http://www.microchip.com/mymicrochip/filehandler.aspx?ddocname=en570134)

[image]